# How do I include an image file when building my Kivy app when converting it to an APK?

Tags: python, kivy, apk, buildozer

I have a very simple kivy python app that I want to turn into an APK. I was going to use Buildozer, but I realized that I need the 2 image files along with the kivy .py file.

Here's my app (when I click a button, it changes the initial image, that's it):

```
from kivy.app import...

class Game(App):
   def build(self):
      
      self.window = GridLayout()
      self.img = Image(source="baby.png")
      self.window.add_Widget(self.img)

      self.button = Button(text="Make him an adult")
      self.button.bind(on_press=self.becomeAdult)

      return self.window

  def becomeAdult(self, instance):
     self.img.source = "adult.png"
```

As you can see, I use 2 images. How can I include them when converting to APK with Buildozer?

Answer (score 0):

In your `buildozer.spec` file, add `img` to the list of Source files to include (`source.include_exts`). Or just comment out that line completely to include every file in your `source.dir`.

Comment: Thanks. Turns out it was already put by default.